# Using a for if break statement to append values in a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, break

I'm working with loops and I got a question, so I have a simple  `for loop` that append random values between 0 and 1, basically what I need is to keep adding values until a certain number of 0 or 1 appear, for example:

```
iteration 1 = [0]
iteration 2 = [0,1]
...
iteration 6 = [0,1,1,1,1,1] #Here appear five 1's so I break the loop (it can be another number not necessarily 5 ones or 5 zeros)
```

The `for loop` is pretty simple:

```
import numpy as np

value = []
for i in range(5):
    value.append(np.random.randint(0, 2))
    print(value)
```

And here is what I tried to break the loop using a `if-break` statement

```
value = []
for i in range(5):
    if value == value:
        value.append(np.random.randint(0, 2))
    else
        break

    print(value)
```

My biggest problem is that I don't know how to specify the codition that if a certain numbers of 0  or 1 appears break the loop, so I was hoping you can point me to a right direction. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such scenarios when you don't know exactly how many number of iterations are required, *using `while` loop is the defacto standard*
You can have two variables as maximum allowed numbers, for this example I'm using `numOnes as 5` and `numbZeros as 3`, use `While True` loop and check for condition at each iteration then break if the condition doesn't satisfy.

```py
import numpy as np
numOnes = 5
numZeros = 3
value = []
while True:
    value.append(np.random.randint(0, 2))
    print(value)
    if value.count(0) >= numZeros or value.count(1)>=numOnes:
        break
```

Since you typically asked about `break` statement, so I used if condition, otherwise you can just have the condition with while loop itself like `while value.count(0) >= numZeros or value.count(1)>=numOnes:`

Also, if you are using `for` loop because you want only specified number of iterations, then your loop is fine and you don't need to use `while` loop, just add the `if` condition at the exit point of loop:

```py
import numpy as np
numOnes = 5
numZeros = 3
value = []
for i in range(5):
    value.append(np.random.randint(0, 2))
    print(value)
    if value.count(0) >= numZeros or value.count(1)>=numOnes:
        break
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the long I can see  things a lot clear now, maybe this a bit of a stretch for what if I need the numbers to be consecutive, in your example, the loop may break when any of those two conditions happen, an example may be [0, 0 ,1, 0] but what if I need that the break happen when  something like this happen: [0, 1, 0 ,0 0] in this case I have the final three consecutive zeros, thank you again.

Comment: @CarlosEduardoCorpus, if you want to check for consecutives, that becomes a different question, but the solution would be to use slice of the resulting list at each iteration and do the comparison. For example: something similar to `value[-numZeros:] == [0]*numZeros`, you can test it, it will give True for `value=[1, 0, 1, 0, 0]` and `numZeros=2`

Comment: Thank you again so much, maybe I should ask a different question.

Answer (score 2):

Use two variables to keep track of the number of 0s and 1s generated by the random number getter.

Then, in the for loop use if-statement logic to append or break where appropriate

Answer (score 2):

You can count the numbers to break.

```py
value = []
count = [0, 0]
while True:
    value.append(np.random.randint(0, 2))
    count[value[-1]] += 1
    if count[1] == 5: # or something like that
        break
```

Edit: if you need consecutive values, you can reset count accordingly when unwanted value comes.

```
    count[value[-1]] += 1
    count[1 - value[-1]] = 0
```

Comment: This code breaks when five ones appear in any position  of the list, but what if need the five ones appear in consecutive order, for example [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], not [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]

Comment: @CarlosEduardoCorpus You can then reset other value count to 0. I edited the post.